# Как установить cookie ( на год) после нажатия кнопки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как установить cookie ( на год) после нажатия кнопки?

```html
<button class="btn">Записать данные в куки на год</button>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie#expires-max-age

Comment: `document.cookie = "<name>=<value>; max-age=31536000";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HTML:
<button class="btn">Записать данные в куки на год</button>
...
JS:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  let UTCDate = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)).toUTCString();
  let name = 'myCookie';
  let value = 'myCookieValue'

  document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; expires=${UTCDate}`;
});
```

Comment: спасибо, а как можно посмотреть в инструментах разработчика куки?

Comment: FF:  `F12 - Storage - Cookies`, Chrome: `F12 - Application - Storage - Cookies`

Comment: смотри через дев тулс- нет

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xuqnhv6L/

Comment: @flowers код рабочий, в Вашем jsfiddle не подключен jquery